# .DS_Store file skipping

Tags: ios, nsfilemanager

In my application I Use NSFileManager to get the number of files in a folder using following code

```
 NSFileManager *manager=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
 NSString *path;
 int numberofFiles=[[manager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:nil] count];
 numberofFiles=numberofFiles-1; //number of files except .DS_Store
```

But my problem is that the file .DS_Store is not always created defaultly, at that time I get less count than the count of files actually present in that directory .

So is there a method in NSFileManager which return the array of files excluding .DS_Store
      or I have to exclude manually using -IsEqualToString method 
      or else is there any option to create a new directory without .DS_Store file.

Comment: You could store `[manager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:nil]` into an `NSArray` and use a [NSPredicate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html) to filter out .DS_Store.

Comment: Check [https://github.com/xiaozhuai/odourless](https://github.com/xiaozhuai/odourless), I made a tool for preventing .DS_Store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicitly look for the `.DS_Store` file and adjust the count if it's found:

```
NSFileManager *manager=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *path = ...;       // Presumably this is a valid path?
NSArray *contents = [manager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:nil];
NSUInteger numberOfFiles = [contents count];
if ([contents indexOfObject:@".DS_Store"] != NSNotFound)
    numberOfFiles--;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. Its working for me..

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *imageFilenames = [manager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];

for (int i = 0; i < [imageFilenames count]; i++)
    {

    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",documentsDirectory,[imageFilenames objectAtIndex:i] ];

        if (![[imageFilenames objectAtIndex:i]isEqualToString:@".DS_Store"])
        {
          UIImage *myimage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imageName];
          UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:_myimage];
        }
    }
```